# How can I write some regex to find subdomain and replace value in Swift

Tags: swift, regex

I have a scenario where legacy `URL` properties I can in my API response have the incorrect sub domain.

For example, `https://profiles.foobar.com` should actually be `https://profiles-v2.foobar.com`

This is the same for all legacy `URL`'s I receive, the subdomain needs to be updated to include `-v2`.

The data will eventually be corrected, however for now I must support the legacy format and new format, so I should check if it is wrong before updating it.

I'd like to write a simple helper function I can use in my models to replace the subdomain with the updated prop if it is incorrect.

Right now I have this in each of my models, but it is essentially duplicated for every possible sub domain and is in each model.

```swift
    private func mapV2ProfileDomain(_ url: URL?) -> URL? {
        guard let urlString = url?.absoluteString else { return nil }

        let mappedString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "https://profiles.", with: "https://profiles-v2.")
        return URL(string: mappedString)
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually using the right method already, `replacingOccurrences` can be made to use a regular expression by setting the `options` parameter to `.regularExpression`

```
let str2 = str.replacingOccurrences(
    of: #"https://(\w*)\."#,
    with: "https://$1-v2.",
    options: .regularExpression
)
```